# How to remove nested element from xml file

Tags: powershell

I need help removing removing multiple element with the same name and also remove multiple element with the same name with nested element

```
$file = [xml]@'
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
    <title>Name</title>
    <date>2019 Jan 01</date>
    <actor>
        <name>Actor Name 1</name>
        <type>Actor</type>
        <thumb>image.jpg</thumb>
    </actor>

    <actor>
        <name>Actor Name 2</name>
        <type>Actor</type>
        <thumb>image.jpg</thumb>
    </actor>

    <genre>genre1</genre>
    <genre>genre2</genre>
</data>
'@
```

I want to remove acotr element and genre element from the xml

I try following but it didnt work.

```
foreach($actor in $file.data.actor)
{
    $actor.RemoveAll()
}
cls
$file.SelectNodes("//actor") | foreach
{
    $file.ParentNode.RemoveChild($_)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the node is a complex type (it has sub elements or attributes), then you can use the following because PowerShell maps this to the node:

```
$file.data.actor| % { $_.ParentNode.RemoveChild($_) | OUT-NULL  }
```

However, this won't work for things like genre because PowerShell maps it as a string.  Instead you can use the following (which will work in either case):

```
$file.data.SelectNodes('genre') | % { $_.ParentNode.RemoveChild($_)  }
```

Comment: That worked. thank you. How would you add the actor element back in again with different value. I'm using following code.foreach ($s in $actors)
{
    $a = $file.data.appendChild($file.CreateElement("actor"))
    $a.AppendChild($file.CreateElement("name")).InnerText=$s.Trim()
    $a.AppendChild($file.CreateElement("type")).InnerText="Actor"
}